# Is it possible to use Object type image in facebook app?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I try and specify a object type of image for my facebook app, it says that it is reserved... so my question is how do i go about creating this object type... or do I not create an object type and use og type article for all my media types... kind regards to any repsonders... J

Answer (score 1):

You may create whatever types you want within your application `namespace` (see [Configuring Object Types](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/#configure)) and later use that in your OpenGraph tags:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="your-og-app:your-type">
```

If you want to use that specific built-in type:

> In order to use build-in object types in your app, you will need to register them in the [Dev App](http://developers.facebook.com/apps).
>
> In addition, we have have created a set of predefined groups of meta tags that can be used as a property of any Open Graph object, called [complex types](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/#complex). Apps should use these types for properties where possible to help the display and aggregation of actions and objects. Because types are not object types, there are no instances. Rather, the values for a complex type are contained in the object that uses them.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. however when i try and give my app an object type of image i get the following    "Sorry, image is reserved and can't be used. Try something more descriptive."

Comment: I have also noticed that although you can create an object type of 'photo', when you do it causes probelms when trying to publish actions... if i use obscure object types like 'myphoto' the exact same code works... but i thoought the whole point of the naemspace was so that I could create an object type of whatever I wanted eg 'image' or 'photo'... that would become... <meta property="og:type" content="your-og-app:your-type">..... (thanks for the response by the way)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `image` Open Graph type. You should use `og:type = article` and set `og:image` to your image thumbnail.

Comment: There is, see `Image` type in [Complex Types](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/#complex)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're trying to make the property's begin with the "og:" prefix. I tried this just now. I entered property name "og:anythingyoulike" (because all the built-in fields begin with "og:") and it came back with this error. Then I just typed "anythingyoulike" into the name input field and it worked fine.

It works fine for common terms like "image", "photo", "duration". Tested all three of those.