# Facebook share only image

Tags: facebook, image, share

I am developing a website where users have the possibility to generate image. I want them to be able to share this image to facebook directly on my page using share button. Not as an article, but as an actual image. Is this possible?

Additionally, as a bonus, is it possible to prompt them option to create a seperate album for it? Since they may share tens and more of these images, it would be good if they wouldb be located on a seperate album or something, so they wont bury other images.

Comment: hi, do yu get results for this? please give me some tips.

Comment: Hi, no, i abandoned the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a website, generally you share the webpage/article. There are many types in the opengraph format including ones for video and music. You should read [the documentation](http://ogp.me/). If you want the image to uploaded to a user's picture section, I'm not sure that is possible, I think you can only put stuff on a user's timeline. You should have also searched first as there is [a stackoverflow question about this already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061814/is-it-possible-to-use-object-type-image-in-facebook-app).