# How to show og:image like a shared url from instagram on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

In Facebook, it shows cool when I share an url of instagram photo.
Big image, title and author in left-bottom, site logo in right-bottom.

For example,
When I share an url of my website, it appears like this: https://db.tt/PnQZsRkT

What can I do for showing like this? : https://db.tt/onxioEnd

Comment: This is what I could achieve http://prntscr.com/3r1i5e. you need to create your own objects, [Using Objects - Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects), [Is it possible to use Object type image in facebook app?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9061814/2151050), by the way this the 2nd time you post this question